# video Not found while add youtube video in magento 2

Tags: magento2, video, youtube

I need to add  product video in magento 2, so, i get youtube api key  add to

**Stores > Settings > Configuration-> Catalog -> Product Videos**  and enter the **youtube api key.**  and **Save Config**

then, clear the cache

then go to 
 **Admin palnel -> Catalog -> Product Detail -> Add Video** then enter the  **Youtube URL key**, then show

```
  Attention

  Error: "Video not found"
```

But, play this video in online. and suggest how to fix this issue.

Note: suggest this also, how to import  product **local videos**(pub/media/videos)  in magento 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add video to product page in Magento 2. To do this follow this [tutorial](http://magenticians.com/add-video-to-product-in-magento-2/). Hope this may help you.

Comment: I miss to enable the key

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Youtube api from google.
2. Get created Api and save as  got Magento admin ==>Stores=> Configuration=>Catalog=> Catalog=>Product Video ==> YouTube API Key  and save
3. Then try to use any youtube url.